# How does thread::join run a script?

Tags: tcl

I see where `thread::create` creates a thread and `thread::send` sends a script to it. But `thread::join` has no script argument. `thread::join` is presented in the manual as if it is a alternate for `thread::send`, but I can't see how to send scripts to a thread if it's joinable.

I see it blocks, which an be useful for some apps, but I don't see the value statement in `thread::join` yet, please give an example of how `thread::join` can run scripts in a separate thread.  Or better explain it's value in a way the manual does not make clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you got the idea that `thread::join` runs a script; it doesn't. What it actually does is send a (C API level) message to the other thread to ask it to terminate gracefully and then waits for the thread to actually terminate; the `thread::wait` command knows how to handle such messages correctly, but most of that is just “run the event loop and watch in case a terminate message comes in” (which is why that command is supposed to always be used as the last one of a thread's body script if it is supposed to become responsive to events).

The actual joinability is about handling the *reverse* message signalling that a thread has really terminated.